# How to resolve 'Invalid window id' error when using Telescope plugin in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

```
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: ...ck/packer/start/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/pickers.lua:756: Invalid 
window id: 1004
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_win_close'
        ...ck/packer/start/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/pickers.lua:756: in function 'close_windows'
        ...ck/packer/start/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/pickers.lua:1501: in function ''
        vim/_editor.lua: in function ''
        vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>
```

Whenever I open telescope and select a command like find_files or colorscheme it throws this error at me. What should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug that was introduced with a recent commit to [nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/commit/3f1b57908b312e7f3bfd919c52c61524a673e622). I would recommend downgrading your telescope.nvim plugin to a version before this commit. The latest tagged release is `v0.1.1`

I also [submitted an issue](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/issues/2532), you could monitor that, but in general it's best not to use the latest commit of a plugin.